# -f command in Perl not working on my system

Tags: perl, directory, command

I have windows 7, I am trying to open a directory and print all filenames in the directory but the -f command is not working on my system. The program is as follows:

```
enter code here

$directory = '\Users';
opendir(DIR, $directory) or die $!;
while ($file = readdir(DIR)){
    if(-f $file){
        print "$file\n";
    }
}
closedir(DIR);
```

can anybody tell me what's wrong?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the path to the file.

It should be something like this:

```
if(-f "$directory/$file") {
```

Comment: @Anmol: If an answer solves your problem then you should mark that as an accepted answer, see this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

You should test with the full path name. `$file` only contains the file name.

```
if ( -f "$directory\\$file" ){
    print "$file\n";
}
```